# Calling axios request one after the other?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, axios

I have tow functions in my ReactJs application called,

1. `AuthService.addUser(newUser);`
2. `AuthService.userCategories(usercategories);`

I want to run these two functions separately, which means the Axios request of the second function should be called after the Axios request of the first function when clicked the submit button. How do I approach the solution? Thanks in advance.

I tried in this way. Is this correct?

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
AuthService.addUser(newUser);
AuthService.userCategories(usercategories);

};
```

Here are my two functions

```
addUser: (user) => {
//console.log(post);
axios
  .post(CONSTANTS.HOSTNAME + "/api/users/register", user)
  .then((res) => {
    //save to local storage
    const { token } = res.data;
    localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
    isAuthenticated.next(true);
    setAuthToken(token);
    Swal.fire({
      icon: "success",
      title: "Signup Successful!",
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500,
    }).then(() => {
      window.location.href = "/";
      //decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      currentUser.next(decoded);
      console.log(decoded);

    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.response.data);
    Swal.fire({
      icon: "error",
      title: "Oops...",
      text: err.response.data,
    });
    // alert(JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
  });
},

userCategories: (userCategories) => {
  axios
    .post(CONSTANTS.HOSTNAME + "/api/users/usercategories", userCategories)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    });

},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use promise if function return promise:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();
  await AuthService.addUser();
  await AuthService.userCategories();
};
```

or make promise from function and run async

```
function one() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('resolve one')
      return resolve("i am after five seconds")
      
    }, 
    2000);
  });
}

function two() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     console.log('resolve two')
    return resolve("i am after three seconds")
    
  });
}

const handleSubmit = async () => {
 console.log('run handleSubmit')
  await one();
  await two();
}

handleSubmit()
```

Comment: how will this work? both of those functions aren't returning any promise.

Comment: here you've got example https://jsfiddle.net/9b18hzsm/

Comment: so should make promise wrapper for your function

Comment: @JanuszO your example is working, but I cannot figure out how to wrap using promises in my two functions. Can you show me how to approach it?